# WebClientRepeating not printing response to Serial

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

I'm following the tutorial in [WebClientRepeating](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClientRepeating) and it says that "The content of the page is viewable through your Arduino's serial window." However the output in my Serial window is just saying "Connecting..." repeatedly.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    /*
  Repeating Web client

 This sketch connects to a a web server and makes a request
 using a Wiznet Ethernet shield. You can use the Arduino Ethernet shield, or
 the Adafruit Ethernet shield, either one will work, as long as it's got
 a Wiznet Ethernet module on board.

 This example uses DNS, by assigning the Ethernet client with a MAC address,
 IP address, and DNS address.

 Circuit:
 * Ethernet shield attached to pins 10, 11, 12, 13

 created 19 Apr 2012
 by Tom Igoe
 modified 21 Jan 2014
 by Federico Vanzati

 http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClientRepeating
 This code is in the public domain.

 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// assign a MAC address for the ethernet controller.
// fill in your address here:
byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};
// fill in an available IP address on your network here,
// for manual configuration:
IPAddress ip(10, 1, 1, 4);

// fill in your Domain Name Server address here:
IPAddress myDns(10, 1, 1, 1);

// initialize the library instance:
EthernetClient client;

char server[] = "www.arduino.cc";
//IPAddress server(64,131,82,241);

unsigned long lastConnectionTime = 0;             // last time you connected to the server, in milliseconds
const unsigned long postingInterval = 10L * 1000L; // delay between updates, in milliseconds
// the "L" is needed to use long type numbers

void setup() {
  // start serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // give the ethernet module time to boot up:
  delay(1000);
  // start the Ethernet connection using a fixed IP address and DNS server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, myDns);
  // print the Ethernet board/shield's IP address:
  Serial.print("My IP address: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  // if there's incoming data from the net connection.
  // send it out the serial port.  This is for debugging
  // purposes only:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if ten seconds have passed since your last connection,
  // then connect again and send data:
  if (millis() - lastConnectionTime > postingInterval) {
    httpRequest();
  }

}

// this method makes a HTTP connection to the server:
void httpRequest() {
  // close any connection before send a new request.
  // This will free the socket on the WiFi shield
  client.stop();

  // if there's a successful connection:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connecting...");
    // send the HTTP GET request:
    client.println("GET /latest.txt HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.arduino.cc");
    client.println("User-Agent: arduino-ethernet");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();

    // note the time that the connection was made:
    lastConnectionTime = millis();
  } else {
    // if you couldn't make a connection:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}
```

Here are my Mac's network settings.

[image]
[image]

It's my understanding that I can assign an IP address to my Ethernet shield by just changing the last number of my computers IP address. Hence I changed 10.1.1.5 to 10.1.1.4.

Can anyone see any obvious errors? This is not really my area of expertise :)

Comment: Might be another device on 10.1.1.4. Try another IP address such as 10.1.1.104.

Comment: Your computer's IP address has no relevance to the Ethernet Shields IP address other than they can't both be the same if connected to the same network. Is your ethernet shield connected to your network/router with a cat5 cable?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using a cat5 cable but the port it was plugged into seemed to be faulty. I tried another one and that seems to have fixed it.